# How to group duplicates using MapReduce?

Tags: mapreduce, duplicates

I want to use MapReduce to return a list of duplicate tuples. By duplicate tuples, I mean tuples having similar values of a set of attributes.

Could I put the values of this set of attributes as an intermediate key and adjust reduce to process all similar keys as one key?

Comment: What to you mean by 'similar keys'? Do you have a specific example?

Comment: @PetrosP my keys are the values of a set of attributes. similarity of keys can be calculated by Levneshtein Distance or any distance.For example we have the values of [PFN,PLN, Tel] as key so key1=('david','robert','1111') and key2('davd','rbrt','1111') and key3('dav','robrt','11111') are similar keys. Certainly Mapreduce when regrouping the liste of values having the same key compare the keys, I want this comparaison to be done by a function of similarity wich I define it and not by equality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I could implement my own class of intermediate key witch implements the ***interface WritableComparable***. So I was forced to implement the function ***CompareTo*** which return **0** if the inputs are equals.

In my case, the attributes' class are the attributes of my tuples. So, I just wrote the function "CompareTo" in such a way that it returns **0** when all these attributes are similar. The similarity here can be computed by the Levenshtein Edit Distance.